# How do I remove the Gnome's video applications?

Tags: gnome

I use VLC to play all my videos, and wanted to know to remove the video player that comes with Gnome.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open a terminal - to do that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> - and execute the following command :

```
sudo apt-get purge totem totem-plugins
```